Postgres sql with regex expression
Trying to run  sql : https://dbfiddle.uk/VlKz_7fg
When I am running sql on fiddle its working fine, however when I am trying to run the same on my database it is throwing - ERROR: invalid regular expression: invalid character class
Can anyone please help how to resolve it..

Your fiddle uses ver 16 of the DB. If you lower it down you will get this error: https://dbfiddle.uk/iFUUelgr
Check your version and what regex it supports.

@PM77-1 : Yes,its version 9.4.26.Can you pls help what do I need to change in regex to support this one?

You use the following character classes:

alpha
word

In the listing of available classes for ver. 9.4 I see alpha but not word. See section 9.7.3.2. in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-matching.html

[[:word:]]
Matches letters, numbers and underscores. Equivalent to \w or [a-zA-Z0-9_].

So replace [[:word:]] with \w.
See 9.4 based Fiddle
